# Mentioning someone in a powerpoint comment will not work unless the user has Contribute

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-web-apps

I have a power-point document published inside SharePoint document library, and we have userA who have read-only permission on the document, and if i try to mention this Read-Only user inside a power-point comment i will get an error that the user can not access the document so i can not mention him inside the comment. But if i grant the user contribute permission on the document i can mention him inside the comment,,, so not sure why the user need to have contribute permission for us to be able to mention him inside a comment? in other words is there a way to mention a Read-Only user?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's by default, the user needs at least contribute permission to be able to be commented on.